# Output Array objects

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to output the value in `[id]` however I'm not sure how to access the "Video Object" to get to the `[id]` value.

I've attempted the following just to see if I get any data response with no success.

```
print_r($arr[0]->video);
```

Here is the whole array.

```
Array ( 
    [0] =>Video Object ( 
        [version] => 1.0 
        [id] => 26696 
        [title] => vztest 
        [description] => 
        [createdAt] => 2009-06-08T14:27:45+00:00 
        [url] => http://view.vzaar.com/26696/video 
        [thumbnail] => http://view.vzaar.com/26696/thumb 
        [playCount] => 0 
        [duration] => 91.33 
        [width] => 320 
        [height] => 200 
        [framegrabUrl] => http://vzaar.com/videos/26696.frame 
        [user] => User Object ( 
            [version] => 
            [authorName] => vzaar 
            [authorId] => 
            [authorUrl] => http://app.vzaar.com/users/vzaar 
            [authorAccount] => 34 
            [createdAt] => 
            [videoCount] => 114 
            [playCount] => 
         )
    )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you -

```
$videoObjectID = $array[0]->id;
```